# LiveData with list doesn't trigger recomposition

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-livedata

I am working on an Android app and retrieving a list from the server which I am writing to a LiveData variable which is meant to update the UI and display the information. However, without any errors the UI simply isn't getting updated.

```
//ViewModel.kt:
//declaration of the list
    private val _backupPlayers = MutableLiveData<List<PlayerModel>>()
    val backupPlayers: LiveData<List<PlayerModel>>
        get() = _backupPlayers

//method that retrieves from server and maps
fun loadPlayers() {
        execute {
            val playersList = mutableListOf<PlayerModel>()

                playerRepository.getPlayers().let { playersResponse ->
                    playersResponse.body()?.map{
                        playersList.add(MapToPlayerModel(it))
                    }
                }

            _backupPlayers.postValue(playersList)
        }
    }

//Screen.kt
//observing the list from the viewmodel
    val backupPlayers = dashboardViewModel.backupPlayers.observeAsState().value

//sample element which isn't updated
     Text(backupPlayers?.count().toString())
```

So far I have tried everything I found on stack overflow and on the internet: trying to make it a mutable list adn adding to it, using .value and assigning instead of .postValue() and so on. Please help. In the rest of the app it works fine with data such as a map, string, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use `observeAsState()` for LiveData as mentioned here.
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#use-other-types-of-state-in-jetpack-compose.

You are using `.observeAsState().value` which only gets the initial value.

---

Add dependency

```
implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.4.3")
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the suggestion! It seems that now data is being loaded. However, it seems that it only works when I run it locally through android studio. When I generate an .aab to use in our internal testing through the Google Play App Console, it doesn't work anymore. This is really weird but is there any chance you have an idea on this?

Comment: That may be a different issue. I don't see any relation.

Comment: @MihaiRaduMiclaus R8 configuration is missing for your JSON parsing